# react native gradlew assembleRelease failed to execute appt

Tags: react-native

First stacktrace:

[image: stacktrace]

I am trying to produce an apk to my project but it always fail and produce the errors in the pictures 
Please Help

Second stacktrace:

[image: stackTrace2]

Comment: code and stacktraces are best copy/pasted in here as code, not as images, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try by use Android Studio open android project inside react native  and clean so build by Android Studio. This way work for me. I just can use gradle build command after update/reinstall Android Studio

Comment: i don't understand you mean i must build the project from android studio then go and run gradlew assemblerelease ?

Comment: use Android Studio to build release version like a normal Android project. Before build remember bundle React Native on project root with command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: no, check this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/ with keyword "Generate Signed APK". it have same effect like "gradle assembleRelease". Or you can try `gradle clean` and run `gradle assembleRelease` again. But if have some missing information like sign key name password so build with Android Studio you can input those info.

Comment: i did run gradle clean then gradle assembleRelease  and i got the same error note i make the appt2 false not true

Comment: I met this same issue before. Try to use Android Studio with UI https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9Ll1DZ8ceY like a normal Android project.

Comment: D:\science\Mobile App\React Native\Projects\picwpost_mobileapp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnavigationstack_dist_views_assets_backicon.png Error:error: Duplicate file.              Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt           Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: it's worked and it's generated apk but when i try to install it on my device it gives me installation failed

Comment: ok, duplicate resource can use this command `rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleRelease` .Installation failed maybe conflict key with previous debug version installed on phone.